# Pandas Groupby Geometric Average?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I'm trying to calculate the stock returns for my portfolio which requires "geometrically averaging" the percentages by year.

For simplicity, I have a dataframe that looks likes this:

Date        Returns

2013-06-01    1%
2013-07-01    5%
2013-08-01   -4%
2014-01-01   12%
2014-02-01   -9%

I'd like the output to show:

Date   Geo Return
2013   1.8%
2015   1.9%

Which is derived by: (1+.01)(1+.05)(1+-.04) = 1.8%

I am able to use the groupby function by year, but it only sums for me and I can't get the geometric average to work. Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have requested the cumulative product, which is different that the usual definition for the geometric mean.

```
df["returns"] = 1 + .01*df.Returns.str.split("%").str[0].astype(int)
df["geom_ave"] = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.year).returns.transform("prod")
```

output:

```
        Date Returns  returns  geom_ave
0 2013-06-01      1%     1.01   1.01808
1 2013-07-01      5%     1.05   1.01808
2 2013-08-01     -4%     0.96   1.01808
3 2014-01-01     12%     1.12   1.01920
4 2014-02-01     -9%     0.91   1.01920
```

If instead you want the geometric mean, you can try:

```
from scipy import stats
series = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.year).returns.apply(stats.gmean)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I do have the year column as a datetime object. Sorry I have a follow up, how would I be able to summarize into a table as follows then?

Date    Geom_Avg
2013     1.01808
2014     1.01920

Comment: @Pho6 you can do: `series = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.year).returns.prod()`